# menu by default should hidden

Tags: php, javascript

Hey guys i want the sensor to be hidden by default and it show when i click on the particular node..and should be the same on page reload 
Here is my code

```
<ul >
<?php if(isset($nodes)): ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($nodes as $node) { ?>
<?php $node_id=$node['node_id']; ?>
<?php $sensors = config_sensor_model::getsensors($node_id); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<li onclick="menu(<?php echo $count; ?>)"><a href="#"><?php echo $node['node_name']; ?> </a></li>
<ul id="<?php echo "sub_".$count; ?>">
<?php foreach($sensors as $sensorlog) { ?> 
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/dashboard/dashboard_graph/?node=<?php echo $node['node_id']; ?>&sensor=<?php echo $sensorlog->sensor_index; ?>&range=0&xticker=2&plot_graphs_value=1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $sensorlog->sensor_name; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>           
<?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

this is the javascript presently i am using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
function menu(count)
{
 $("#sub_"+count).toggle("fast");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh God my eyes are burning.. anyway can you explain what is wrong exactly? If you're `toggle`-ing it, they should be hidden. But note that you're probably better off using CSS solution for this to hide the children. There are many examples of a multi-level menu on the internet.

Comment: do you have a solution for it Rudi... No presently they are not hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment just use CSS to hide the node initially like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden { display: none; }
</style>

<ul>
if(isset($nodes)):
    $count = 0;
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        $node_id = $node['node_id'];
        $sensors = config_sensor_model::getsensors($node_id);
        $count++;
        ?>
        <li onclick="menu(<?php echo $count; ?>)"><a href="#"><?php echo $node['node_name']; ?> </a></li>
        <ul id="<?php echo "sub_".$count; ?>" class="hidden">
            <?php foreach($sensors as $sensorlog) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/dashboard/dashboard_graph/?node=<?php echo $node['node_id']; ?>&sensor=<?php echo $sensorlog->sensor_index; ?>&range=0&xticker=2&plot_graphs_value=1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $sensorlog->sensor_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>           
    <?php }
endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

When menu is clicked, the `display` value will be toggled by Javascript.

Comment: yeah...! its working but on reloading  of the page its again the sensor are getting hidden for the particular node i selected

Comment: hey Rudi it working fine but on page reload its the sensors names of the node i am selecting are getting hidden i don't want that to happen  can u provide a solution to that

Answer (score 0):

Set `style='display:none'` for the `<ul>`